# PHP Imagick PDF preview incorrect - gives a adobe reader message

Tags: php, imagick

I am using Imagick in php to generate a preview of a pdf in a web page. There is no problem in generation , However for some pdfs the image generation shows the message "To view full contents of the pdf you need a latest version of pdf viewer ". How do i solve the problem?

Here is the code

```
if (file_exists($file))
        {
            $im = new imagick($file);
            $im->setimageformat('jpeg');
            header( "Content-Type: image/jpeg" );
            echo $im;
            exit;
        }
```

Comment: I am trying to find a solution which produces a image preview of a active pdf with no luck. Can some one point me in the right direction

Comment: I am trying to find a solution which produces a image preview of a active pdf with no luck. Can some one point me in the right direction